# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Organizing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm having a ASP.NET MVC 2 Project where I'm making some management system... The thing is that I have 4-5 controllers that are all related to a specific thing in the management system and having 4-5 diffrent view folders dosent make it any easier.. Any suggestions? Since its "a part" of the management system I dont really see how I can make use of areas. All ideas welcome.

**UPDATE:**

For example I have a thing in my management system called "Product Management", this thing have following controllers attached:

- CategoriesController =
  Add/Delete/Edit categories.
- ProductsController = Add/Delete/Edit
  products in categories.
- OrdersController = Add/Delete/Edit
  orders from users.

Seems like a waste that I need to create 3 diffrent view folders for those controllers.. Would be much easier if I could create a folder under the "Views" named "Product Management" and then just create a sub folder for each controller...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can arrange it that way.

You can create an Area as `ProductManagement` and have your controllers/views inside it.

Comment: Dont think areas are what I'm looking for.. check the update in my post for more details :)

Comment: It sounds like areas are *exactly* what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the pages under Shared folder, so that they can be picked up by View engine can find and render the page.

If this is not the solution you are looking at, can you please elaborate your problem further?